# How to clear the columns data when click CREATE button in oracle APEX?

Tags: oracle-apex

I created Form with report in APEX and when I click CREATE button its open the form
and the column filled with data .

How can I clear the data from columns when click create button and open the form ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the session values of pages items are not reset when a form is submitted - that needs to be done explicitely. If it's not done, then you'll get the behaviour you're seeing: when opening a page the values that were entered last time the page was visited during the session are still visible. Best practice is to use the "Clear Cache" attribute in the link to the form. That will ensure all page items on the page for which that attribute is set will be cleared:

[image]

There are other places where cache can be reset (eg in a branch or using the "clear session state" page process).